# MySQL 5.5 vs 5.6,5.7 above same database same query but different output, limit have duplicated ID

Tags: mysql, order-by, duplication, limits, wordpress

I am using Running same source code and same database for WordPress, only the mysql version is different. It make my pagination post have duplication.
Here is what I found out. Any idea how to solve it in higher version?

This is for Page 2, and Page 3 query output. Left-Hand side is MySql 5.5, Right-Hand side is MySql 5.6.  up_posts.ID is unique.

SQL Statement:-

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS up_posts.ID FROM up_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND up_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (up_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR up_posts.post_status = 'closed' OR up_posts.post_status = 'private' OR up_posts.post_status = 'hidden')  ORDER BY up_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 10, 10

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS up_posts.ID FROM up_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND up_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (up_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR up_posts.post_status = 'closed' OR up_posts.post_status = 'private' OR up_posts.post_status = 'hidden')  ORDER BY up_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 20, 10
```

Page 2:- different is LIMIT 10,10
[image: Page 2]

Page 3:- different is LIMIT 20,10
[image: Page 3 - as you can see ID:62728 & 62737 appear again in Page 3]

Seem like MySQL 5.5 will sort by the ID, but 5.6 above does not have this ability.

Comment: Without proper ORDER BY there's no guaranteed output in a DBMS, MySQL seems to evolve :-)

Comment: @dnoeth arg... shouldn't it behaviour like 5.5 order by id to avoid this duplicated result... MySQL MySQL? can consider this is bug?

Comment: Not a bug. This is expected. Non-deterministic `ORDER BY` produces non-deterministic results.

Comment: You are asking why WP+MySQL fails to get the same get the same answer in two situations?  Because WP has a bug.  _Not_ MySQL.  File a bug report with them and cite this Q&A as a discussion of how it should be fixed in WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `ORDER BY up_posts.post_date DESC, up_posts.ID DESC` no more duplicate result. Seem like we need to manually add this to avoid an unnecessary problem.

FYI. It applied to MySQL 5.6 and 5.7.

See [8.2.1.16 LIMIT Query Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html)

If you want to order by primary key, you have to say so explicitly.